# Traefik proxy HTTPS

Tags: traefik

I am setting up a very simple Traefik service. I just want t demo something like NGINX `proxy_pass` to point to Wikipedia. Things work expect (unlike NGINX) it is not rendering the actual page. I instead get the "our servers are currently under maintenance" page. What documentation can I reference so that this works like NGINX?

I'm sure it's something simple I am missing. This is just for a demo, so I just need the actual page to pop up and not the warning page.

Thanks!

## Root Configuration

```yaml
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: :8080

providers:
  providersThrottleDuration: 2s
  file:
    directory: /backend-services/
    watch: true

log:
  level: DEBUG
```

## Dynamic Configuration

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    wikipedia-router:
      entryPoints:
        - http
      rule: "Path(`/`)"
      service: wikipedia-service

  services:
    wikipedia-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "https://www.wikipedia.org"
```

## NGINX Configuration that Works

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://www.wikipedia.org;
    }
}
```